# Get 3D Matrix dimension as a Vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

In Matlab, if I were to have a 3D Matrix as follows:-

```
>> T = rand(4,4,3)

T(:,:,1) =

    0.3214    0.0986    0.4552    0.4033
    0.2283    0.8989    0.7460    0.8627
    0.9535    0.5170    0.6831    0.6013
    0.1657    0.7017    0.9876    0.9445


T(:,:,2) =

    0.5260    0.2102    0.2393    0.9158
    0.8759    0.2099    0.5677    0.4351
    0.5829    0.5325    0.9171    0.7946
    0.5918    0.6938    0.0176    0.0641


T(:,:,3) =

    0.7209    0.7310    0.8726    0.0960
    0.3021    0.1482    0.0549    0.2180
    0.2190    0.4476    0.4889    0.5725
    0.7653    0.3743    0.9298    0.1413
```

And I wanted to obtain all of the elements in the dimensions `(1,1,:)`, how would it be done?

I have tried the following:-

```
t = T(1,1,:)
```

But it yields:-

```
t(:,:,1) =

    0.3214


t(:,:,2) =

    0.5260


t(:,:,3) =

    0.7209
```

However, I wish to perform a vector product operation on the values as a vector, like so:-

```
t = [0.3214, 0.5260, 0.7209]
v2 = t*v'
```

and then perform some modifications to `t`, storing the resulting vector back into the 3D Matrix `T`.

I would like to do this in a vectorized manner if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%get t, removing all singleton dimensions
t=squeeze(T(1,1,:))
%some operations
t=t*rand(1)
%writing t back
T(1,1,:)=t
```

Comment: I forgot about `squeeze`. Perfect for making a row vector here.

Comment: @Daniel R Thank you, I like this a lot.

Answer (score 4):

[`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
t = reshape(T(1,1,:),1,[]);
```

Or [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
t = permute(T(1,1,:),[1 3 2])
```

Both options above give a row vector. For a column vector: `t = reshape(T(1,1,:),[],1);` and `t = permute(T(1,1,:),[3 2 1])`.

You do not need to match dimensions to write back (e.g. `T(1,1,:) = v2;` will suffice).

Comment: For a row vector you can also use `squeeze`: `squeeze(T(1,1,:))`

Comment: @LuisMendo True -- I see that Daniel gave that option. Myself, I like to explicitly specify dimensions, mainly for readability, but also to avoid possible bugs.

Comment: @chappjc Thank you very much for the response and solution. However, I do really like the 'squeeze' option. So, although this is a brilliant pair of solutions, I think I will accept Daniels answer.